# ProgressBar Spinner for Async Task

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Here is my simple AsyncTask :

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String page = null;
        try {
            page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return page;
    }
```

how do I add a progress bar to this that displays a simple spinner? Every time I try the code breaks or parameters are misplaced.

EDIT:

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog myPd_ring = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


        myPd_ring.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        String page = null;
        try {
            page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return page;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        myPd_ring.dismiss();        
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Tried this still doesn't work ! In fact the application isn't even responding to standard input now !
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            myPd_ring  = new ProgressDialog (YourActivityName.this);
            myPd_ring.setMessage("Forza Roma");
            myPd_ring.show();

        }
```

Also change your class to

```
class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
```

and on `onPostExecute` function you should call the super function first like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {        
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        myPd_ring.dismiss();
}
```

Furthermore, for your business logic, you should call new AsyncTask in the `onPostExecute` not on `doInBackground`

Comment: @WilliamKinnan Shows The constructor ProgressDialog() is undefined

Comment: you need to import `android.app.ProgressDialog`

Comment: @Anurupa_Dey I just forget to tell you that the constructor should take the YourActivityName.this as a parameter, check the update please

Comment: @WilliamKinaan Please explain :( Sorry but am just a beginner !

Comment: check my update, the ProgressDialog class take an attribute which is the context that you are working on, you can get the context by typing `yourActivityName.this`, lets say your activity name is `Player` so the the constructor will be `new ProgressDialgo(Player.this);`

Comment: however, you could also say `new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext())`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan My class myTask is defined in the MainActivity.java below the class MainActivity. It's not on a separate file. So whenever I try to do this.mainActivity it shows: MainActivity cannot be resolved or is not a field.

I tried this:
`ProgressDialog myPd_ring;
 
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  
  myPd_ring  = new ProgressDialog(this.MainActivity);
  myPd_ring.setMessage("Getting Data");
        myPd_ring.show();`

that produced the error.

Comment: @Anurupa_Dey you should do this: `myPd_ring  = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);`

Comment: @WilliamKinaan shows the error No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope

Comment: that code contains many errors, first, you should do this `String page = new MyTask().execute(url);` without get, second, the code after it should be in the `onPostExecute`, third the `myPd_ring  = new ProgressDialog( );` should be `myPd_ring  = new ProgressDialog( MainActivity.this);`, also there are many problems, please split your code to pieces of codes and try every one alone.

Answer (score 0):

override the method `onPreExecute()`

in that method create a ProgressDialog and show it.
You can dismiss the ProgressDialog in the method `onPostExecute()` that you should also override. Check out more about the AsyncTask [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2012/12/using-asynctask.html)

Be careful using AsyncTasks though, it has some hidden pitfalls. Check out [this article](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/04/the-dark-side-of-asynctask.html) about it.

Comment: tried this: 

`class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 
 ProgressDialog myPd_ring = null;
 
 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  
  
  myPd_ring.show();

 }
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

  String page = null;
  try {
   page = new Communicator().executeHttpGet(params[0]);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return page;
  
 }
 
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
  myPd_ring.dismiss();  
  super.onPostExecute(result);
 }

}`

Doesn't work and broke the code :(

Comment: of course, myPd_ring is still null and you try to show it. add myPd_ring = new ProgressDialog() (or something like that) before myPd_ring.show()